# Linux + Phinx + XAMPP = ERROR - need enable PDO_Mysql extension

Tags: linux, xampp, php-7, phinx

Could you tell me please, what should I do with this Phinx error. When I tried to run phinx migrate command in console, it throws me an error "You need to enable the PDO_Mysql extension for Phinx to run properly."
Environment is Linux, XAMPP, PHP 7. As I can see in phpinfo() result PDO_Mysql is enabled. So where is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Php7 /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo\_mysql.so is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360144/linux-php7-usr-lib-php-20151012-pdo-mysql-so-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (php 5) I re installed php-gd and php-mysql.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd php5.6-mysql
```

And works as well.

I hope this can help you.